# BCP failing when using __$Operation in column list

Tags: sql-server, bcp

```
bcp "select __$Operation from ##t" queryout "C:\sample.csv" -c -t -C 1252, -T -S myserver
```

This column is present in `sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn table`.

Error:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = S0022, NativeError = 207
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name '__'.
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations
```

Comment: @Chanukya How is this related to question asked?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/bcp-in-of-datetime-type-data-results-in-an-invalid-date-time-format

Comment: @Chanukya It's not a datatype issue, its column name issue